# Datables how to sort by on screen rendered mData

Tags: sorting, datatables, render

HI am using fnRender/mData to get some values and do a distance function before displaying on screen. How do i sort by the data that is being seen onscreen by user?

The data is using `"bServerSide": true, "bProcessing": true,` but the distance is being calculated client side and i need to be able to order after the distance has been calculated client side, if the user clicks on sort by the distance column

```
 {
            "sClass": "ellipsis",
            "mData": function (oObj, type, val) {

                if ($('#lat').val() > 0 && $('#searchbox').val() != '')
                {
                    var distance = distanceTo(oObj[14], oObj[9], $('#lat').val(), $('#long').val(), "K");
                    return distance.toFixed(2);
                }
                else
                {
                    return '';
                }
            },
            "bSearchable": false },
```

Comment: Note: i am using the old datatables

Comment: Are you using client-side or server-side (`"bServerSide": true`) processing?

Comment: Which one, client-side or server-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using server-side processing mode, filtering, sorting and paging is performed by you server-side script.

Send values of `#lat` and `#searchbox` to the server using [`fnServerParams`](https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side) option and replicate your logic in your server-side script to achieve the effect you want.

That means you also need to calculate the distance by your server-side script.

Alternatively, if your dataset is small, you can switch to client-side processing mode and the sorting would work.

Comment: @Beginner If your data set is small (for example, under 10000 records), you can switch to client-side processing mode and the sorting would work.

Comment: If i was able to calculate server side then i would just set it to a distance variable on the datatable and i know it will sort fine then. I was hoping i would not have to work the distance out on the server and could get away with doing it on the cleint

Comment: @Beginner, can you switch to client-side processing mode, see updated answer?

Comment: i am able to look through the entire data set to do some other stuff ...

Comment: $(aData).each(function (index) {
       $(".it").append("<div class='mapdata' id='" + nFoot + "B' title='" + aData[index][14] + "|" + aData[index][15] + "' data-id='true' ></div >");
            });

Comment: can i not lopp through and use this to sort some how?

Comment: im thinking about something like disabling the server side sorting when the distance column is clicked on. and doing it client side with the aData?